# In Stoke's second problem, why can the pressure gradient be set to 0?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, navier-stokes

In every derivation of solution to Stokes second problem (where we need to find the flow of a fluid under an oscillating plate on the $x$-axis), the pressure gradient is always taken to be 0 to simplify the Navier-Stokes equation.  Why is that the case? Surely he closer we are to the plate the higher the pressure would be and further away from the plate the pressure would decrease?

Comment: The "Stokes second problem" is modelled on an infinitely long plate and the fluid is taken to be incompressible. That is, there are no density variations. It's not taken to be zero to "simplify the NS equation". There is simply no need to include it.

Comment: I understand that there are no density variations. However, why does that then mean there is no pressure gradient? (In other setups the pressure gradient isn't necessarily 0 if we assume an incompressible flow)

Comment: "_In other setups the pressure gradient isn't necessarily 0 if we assume an incompressible flow_" Example? Incompressibility is synonymous with constant density. If the pressure in a fluid varies from point to point, so too does the density, which is contradictory to our first premise. For this setup, the pressure is taken to be equal at all points in the flow, so there is no gradient.

Comment: Does the solution with no pressure gradient satisfy the NS equations and BC's?